# Why does Windows Phone events or callbacks have a limit of 10 seconds to execute?

Tags: windows-phone-7, events, time, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I think the title says it all !

I've read that in Windows Phone "all application lifecycle events enforce a limit of 10 seconds for an application to complete any tasks."

Does anyone knows why is it 10 seconds ? Why not more ? Why not less ? Is it really 10 seconds ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to [this quote on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> **The Closing Event**
>
> The Closing event is raised when the user navigates
>   backwards past the first page of an app. In this case, the app is
>   terminated and no state is saved. In the Closing event handler, your
>   app can save data that should persist across instances. There is a
>   limit of 10 seconds for an app to complete all application and page
>   navigation events. If this limit is exceeded, the application is
>   terminated. For this reason, it is a good idea to save persistent
>   state throughout the lifetime of the application and avoid having to
>   do large amounts of file I/O in the Closing event handler.

This is scoped to the Closing of the application. In other words: the user want to leave your app in way he won't be able to go back to it. (backwards beyond the first page of the app)

In this case all that app should do is save state it really needs the next time an dpass control as quickly as possible in order to have a decent user experience (speed!) Apparently Microsoft decided that 10 seconds is the most that a user should be bothered by the clossing of an app.

From the same page:

> Remember that all application lifecycle events enforce a limit of 10 seconds for an application to complete any tasks.

Note that the 10 second limit is imposed on **lifecycle events.**

In general: an app should be responsive. What you should/could do, is save state as soon as state that should be persisted has been changed and/or as soon as a page navigation kicks in. That way you do not have to save all state when closing the app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was exactly referring to that section on MSDN ! I would like to understand the 10 seconds limit imposed on lifecycle events... They have probably made some tests or surveys... that's what i would like to find.

Comment: They are probably not going to tell you :)